# Substituir nome de arquivo via prompt MSDOS

Tags: prompt, ms-dos

Estou criando uma job e gostaria de substituir parte do nome de um arquivo.

Utilizo o seguinte:

```
"rename" | caminho onde devo atualizar + nome_anterior | novo_nome
```

Porem, usando a opção acima, o padrão de nome do meu arquivo fica invalido.

Por exemplo:
Meu arquivo: `TESTE_ARQUIVO_202111301`
Novo Arquivo: `NOVO_20211301`(deveria ser)

Porem, usando o comando acima, meu arquivo fica assim:

Código utilizado: `rename \\\caminho onde devo atualizar\TESTE_ARQUIVO_* NOVO_*`
Resultado ocorrido: `NOVO__ARQUIVO_202111301`
Resultado esperado: `NOVO_20211301`

Nesse caso, preciso apenas substituir `"TESTE_ARQUIVO_"` por `"NOVO_"` , e manter o restante da informação de `TESTE_ARQUIVO_data do arquivo`, mas o comando não faz substring como eu preciso.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

`*/ EDIT`

**1.** Você tem que usar *variable replace/substring* (modificações no conteúdo da cadeia de caracteres na variável que guarda o nome), no seu caso, defina o nome e opere as substituições:

- Removendo strings na variável (*usando **replace** sem substituições*):

```batch-file
Set "_Var=!_Var:    String    =       ⇩       !" <==>  Set "_Var=!_Var:String=!"
Set "_Var=!_Var:    String    = N a d a  A q u i !" <==>  Set "_Var=!_Var:Remover=!"  
Set "_Var=!_Var:TESTE_ARQUIVO_= N a d a  A q u i !" <==>  Set "_Var=!_Var:TESTE_ARQUIVO_=!"
```

- Substituindo strings na variável (*usando **replace***):

```batch-file
Set "_Var=!_Var:    String    =      ⇩      !" <==>  Set "_Var=!_Var:string=adicionar!"
Set "_Var=!_Var:    String    = Substituir Por !" <==>  Set "_Var=!_Var:Replace=EssaString!"  
Set "_Var=!_Var:TESTE_ARQUIVO_= Substituir Por !" <==>  Set "_Var=!_Var:TESTE_ARQUIVO_=NOVO_!"
```

**2.** Usar o comando `Rename string*.* stringNOVO_*.*` é muito vago para execução em um ou múltiplos arquivos/nomes, não funciona bem assim:

- Comando **`rename`** e como o interpretador de comandos (**[cmd.exe](/questions/tagged/cmd.exe)**) vai assumir/entender e executar *"mecanicamente"*:

```batch-file
rem ::  vai renomear todos os arquivos de todas as extensões
rem ::  onde a string no nome literalmente bata com "a_string"
rem ::  alterando para "b_string" apenas o nome e mantendo a extensão:

        >rename a_string.*         b_string.*
rem ::  resulta a_string.txt  ==>  b_string.txt 
rem ::  resulta a_string.jpg  ==>  b_string.jpg 
rem ::  resulta a_string.rar  ==>  b_string.rar
```

```batch-file
rem ::  vai renomear todos os arquivos com a extensão .txt onde o primeiro 
rem ::  caractere no nome bater com "a" e a sua extensão for igual ".txt", 
rem ::  alterando o primeiro caractere "a" no nome para "b", e mantendo
rem ::  as outras strings no nome e a extensão do arquivo:
rem ::  susbtituir o primeiro caractere a por b

        >rename a*.txt             b*.txt
rem ::  resulta a_string.txt  ==>  b_string.txt
```

```batch-file
rem ::  vai renomear todos os arquivos com a extensão .txt onde o primeiro caractere no
rem ::  nome for igual a "a", e alterando o tambem o segundo caractere no nome, onde
rem ::  o primeiro ele vai alterar de "a" para "b", e o (um) segundo caracter
rem ::  qualquer, ele vai alterar de "?" para "b", e mantendo as strings restantes
rem ::  (do terceiro carater ao último caractere) no nome e a sua extensão sem
rem ::  alterações, alterando o primeiro e um segundo caractere no nome
rem ::  susbtituir o primeiro e o segundo caractere por bb 

        >rename a*.txt bb*.txt
rem ::  resulta a_string.txt  ==> bbstring.txt
```

```batch-file
rem ::  vai renomear todos os arquivos com a extensão .txt onde o primeiro caractere no 
rem ::  nome for igual a "a", e alterando o tambem o segundo e terceiro caracteres no 
rem ::  nome, onde o primeiro ele vai alterar de "a" para "b", o (um) segundo caracter
rem ::  qualquer e o (um) terceiro caracter qualquer ele vai alterar de "??" para "bb",
rem ::  e mantendo as strings restantes (do quarto carater ao último caractere) no
rem ::  nome e sua extensão sem alterações, assim soment alterando o primeiro, 
rem ::  o segundo e também o terceiro caractere no nome do arquivo
rem ::  susbtituir primeiro, segundo e terceiro caractere por bbb 

        >rename a*.txt bbb*.txt
rem ::  resulta a_string.txt ==>  bbbtring.txt
```

```batch-file
rem ::  da mesma forma que ocorreu nas ações acima, você também voce 
rem ::  pode entender que o ocorreu com o seu comando, onde os seus 
rem ::  cinco primeiros caracteres foraam susbtituidos por 
rem ::  outros cinco caracteres, renomeando o seu arquivo:
rem ::    de "TESTE_ARQUIVO_*"
rem ::  para "NOVO_*" 
rem ::
rem ::    O contraio também não funciona:
rem ::
rem ::    // nome de origem não é explicitado, é selecionado
rem ::    de "NOVO_*"
rem ::    // nome de destino não é explicitado, é selecionado  
rem ::  para "TESTE_ARQUIVO_*"
```

**3.** Para entender o que ocorre, precisa perceber a diferença de selecionar x explicitar:

```batch-file
rem ::  nome de arquivo é passado para o interpretador por seleção
rem ::  todos os arquivos que iniciam por TESTE_ARQUIVO_ e contenha
rem ::  qualquer comprimento de carateres (*) após a string TESTE_ARQUIVO_, 
rem ::  passe ao comando interno rename/ren o (ou cada) arquivo para renomear 
rem ::  para NOVO_+todas as strings restantes, assim substituindo no arquivo(s) 
rem ::  selecionado(s), os cinco primeiras caracteres no nome, no seu caso, subtituir 
rem ::  TESTE pelos cinco caracters passadas na selação para destino, NOVO_

        >rename "TESTE_ARQUIVO_*.txt" "NOVO_*.txt"
rem ::  resulta TESTE_ARQUIVO_202111301.txt  ==>  NOVO__ARQUIVO_202111301.txt

rem :: passando de forma explicita os nomes de de origem e destino
        >rename "TESTE_ARQUIVO_202111301.txt" "NOVO_20211301.txt"
```

**4.** Seria o caso de usar um `for` loop para tornar os nomes de arquivo de origem a serem passados em variáveis que possam expandir para a forma explicita, e igualmente com os nomes de destino, mas nesses, usando variáveis com os replaces facilitando o uso de forma explicita:

```batch-file
for %i in ("\\caminho onde devo atualizar\*nome_anterior*.*")do set "_Nome=%~nxi" && cmd/v/c (ren "%~i" "!_Nome:Teste_Arquivo_=!")

rem ::  esse loop vai te trazer em %i, o caminho completo e o nome do arquivo 
rem ::  de forma já explicita de cada arquivo que atende a seleção, dai é 
rem ::  fazer uso no comando rename "%~i" ....

rem ::  defina o nome que retona na variavel %~i, já expandindo a variavel 
rem ::  para a forma explita compondo com replace, o nome explicito do destino
rem ::  Nome eXtensão de %i 
rem ::  set "_Nome=%~nxi"

rem :: force a expanção da variável com atraso em tempo de execução 
rem :: para remover !_Nome:Teste_Arquivo_=!
rem :: "!_Nome:Teste_Arquivo_=!"

rem ::  as duas ações um só comando
rem ::  set "_Nome=%~nxi" && cmd/v/c (ren "%~i" "!_Nome:Teste_Arquivo_=!")
```

`EDIT */`

---

---

---

> `rename \\caminho onde devo atualizar\TESTE_ARQUIVO_* NOVO_`

Você esta tentando aplicar/usar uma sintaxe do `cmd/rename` no PowerShell, não funciona bem assim...

```batch-file
Get-ChildItem -File '\\caminho onde devo atualizar' | rename-item -NewName {$_.name -replace 'ARQUIVO_',''} -WhatIf
```

`Get-ChildItem -File` lista os seus arquivos

- Usando alias:

```batch-file
gci -af '\\caminho onde devo atualizar' | ren -New {$_.name -replace 'ARQUIVO_',''} -WhatIf
```

---

**Obs.: 1** Não se aplica a sub-diretórios, nesses casos use: `-Directory` ou `-re`

`| ren -new` Cada item/arquivo listado é redirecionado para renomear já definindo o novo nome onde é removido a string `ARQUIVO_`

---

**Obs.: 2** Para aplicar subpastas e não em arquivos, remova `-FILE | -af` e adicione recursividade `-Directory` ou `-ad`

```batch-file
gci -ad -r '\\caminho onde devo atualizar' | ren -New {$_.name -replace 'ARQUIVO_',''} -WhatIf
```

---

**Obs.: 3** Usando **`-WhatIf`**, o PowerShell te dá uma previsão das ações que serão executadas, sem efetivamente alterar nada, então use para se certificar que o comando será aplicado da pasta e arquivos corretos, depois é so remover `-WhatIf`

```batch-file
gci -af '\\caminho onde devo atualizar' | ren -New {$_.name -replace 'ARQUIVO_',''}
```

---

**Obs.: 4** Para aplicar a ação somente a uma extensão definida:

```batch-file
gci -af '\\caminho onde devo atualizar\*.xlsx' | ren -New {$_.name -replace 'ARQUIVO_',''} -WhatIf
```

---

**Obs.: 5** Para aplicar a ação a um grupo de extensões definidas:

```batch-file
'*.pdf','*.txt','*.rar' | % {gci -af -r '\\caminho onde devo atualizar' | ren -New {$_.name -replace 'ARQUIVO_',''} -WhatIf }
```

---

- Algumas referências para leituras adicionais (`/English`):

  [√]  **[Get-ChildItem | gci | ls | dir](https://ss64.com/ps/get-item.html)**

  [√]  **[Rename-Item | ren | -NewName | -New](https://ss64.com/ps/rename-item.html)**

  [√]  **[Don't fear hitting enter with `-Whatif`](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/powershell-basics-don-t-fear-hitting-enter-with-whatif/ba-p/353579)**

  [√] **[Foreach-Object | % | ?](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)**

Comment: Entao, esse comando preciso executar no prompt MSDOS, e nao no Powershell (Titulo atualizado)....

Comment: prompt MSDOS? Ele não foi extinto na década de 90? Prompt MS-DOS é a mesma coisa que cmd?

Comment: @yoyo Isso tá mais para modo de falar que faz referência/associação ao `prompt de comando` 
 no atual interpretador de comando (`cmd.exe` para os antigos usuários do `command.com` no `Prompt/MS-DOS`)

Comment: @ValterSilva Eh que me guiei pela **Tag** **[PowerShell](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell)** de sua **[edição anterior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ay9Fs.png)**